# Mostrar saltos de linea en laravel

Tags: laravel-blade

Buenas tengo un campo donde muestro un mensaje que un usuario ingresa a la base de datos, el problema que tengo es que cuando recupero dicho texto no me muestra los saltos de linea ejemplo:

```
Esto

es un
texto de prueba.
```

Pero me lo devuelve de la siguiente manera `*Esto es un texto prueba*`

Intente ingresar los datos con nl2br pero me devuelve el texto con los `Esto<br /> es un <br /> texto de prueba`

En mi código estoy recuperando el texto de esta manera `{{  nl2br($item->body)  }}`

Ya lo e intentado de mil formas incluso con `$str = str_replace("<br/>", "\n", $item->body);` pero no se que es lo que me esta fallando.

Comment: Primero que todo, como se guarda el texto en tu BD

Comment: El texto lo almaceno de esta manera  `$this->body = nl2br($this->body)` lo acabo de solucionar con el comentario de Gerardo `{!! $item->body !!}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tiene saltos de linea guardados en formato html puede hacer  `{!! $item->body !!}`

Comment: Hay que aclararle al OP que esto es una práctica riesgosa

Comment: Cual es el riesgo?

Comment: Aquí puedes leer al respecto https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Ok enterado....

Comment: Acabo de mirar lo que comentas sobre que es practica riesgosa, sin embargo como podría solucionarlo utilizando las dobles {{ }}, solo necesito recuperar los saltos de linea.

Answer (score -1):

la usar **nl2br()** genera saltos de línea de HTML `</br>`, para que sean visibles debes usar

```
{!! nl2br($this->body) !!}
```